Search User in chat Channel List page like WhatsApp in getstream-io getstream-chat in Flutter
I am using Stream SDK in my app using flutter so in chat channel list screen I want to search user by name or number and Navigate to chat screen by clicking on the user like WhatsApp. I am trying so many ways but not getting my requirement.
Stream SDK gives Search by messages in chat channel list page and search by user when want to create a new chat or group chat. but like WhatsApp we want to search user in chat channel list page by name or number and navigate to chat screen. Is Stream providing any ways to Do This.
